# QT needs a compiler set up to build

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, ubuntu, compiler-construction

Operating system is ubuntu 12.04. I have downloaded and installed QT 5.0.2 (64bit linux). Then when I try to debug something, it says
:-1: error: Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build
Configure a compiler in the kit options.
I've already installed mingw but QT doesn't auto-detect it. (I don't know even if it is supposted ro do that).

Comment: Try to `apt-get install build-essential`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compiler can be installed on Ubuntu using a simple command:

```
apt-get install build-essential
```